# Problem with _.filter method in lodash in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, lodash, mailchimp

My objective is to delete every row in a CSV for which there are already email addresses in mailchimp.

I tried this function but it doesn't give me the right number of elements:

```
async function testDeleteEmails(listID, csvFileLocation){
  csvContent = fs.readFileSync(csvFileLocation, "utf-8");
  let { data } = Papa.parse(csvContent, { header: true, skipEmptyLines: true });
  let duplicateEmails = await compareArrayEmailsMailchimpAndCSV (fetchMailchimpMembersEmails(listID), getArrayEmailsFromLocalCSV(csvFileLocation))
  let newCSV = _.filter(data, function(row){
      return _.includes(duplicateEmails, row["Email of user"])
  })
  console.log(newCSV)
}
testDeleteEmails("MY LIST ID", ".../myCSV.csv")
```

`compareArrayEmailsMailchimpAndCSV` is a function to get an array of all duplicate email addresses (those in mailchimp and those in my CSV)

I have 1058 email addresses in mailchimp. 960 email addresses in my CSV and my function `compareArrayEmailsMailchimpAndCSV` give me 797 email addresses so if I'm correct I have 163 email addresses to keep in my CSV. When I'm using the function `testDeleteEmails` it give me 869 email addresses, which is not what I want. Am I using the lodash method wrongly?

Knowing that I have to do it dynamically because I have to do it with other list and CSV file.

I know the function is not finished, when the `newCSV` data will be correct, I'll just have to unparse the data and put it in a CSV file.

Comment: Please provide a more minimal example

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm gonna edit my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue doesn't regarding the Lodash filter.
I think the issue is in your CSV file. Maybe there are duplicate email addresses in the CSV.
Please check Your CSV file.
You can check it using the uniqueBy function from the Lodash.

```
  const uniqueData = _.uniqBy(data, 'Email of user');
```

And check the lengths of the data and uniqueData.

Comment: Well when I'm using `_.uniqBy` it says that I have 883 datas in my array

Comment: Wait it look like the problem is coming from `duplicateEmails` because it says that I have only 1 uniqueData in it when I'm doing this: `const uniqueData2 = _.uniqBy(duplicateEmails, "Email of user")`

Comment: But when I'm doing a `console.log(duplicateEmails` I have 797 emails in it and they are not duplicate

Comment: The length of `data` is 960

Comment: Are the objects in the duplicate Emails collection has the "Email of user" key? I don't think so

Comment: No sorry, but when I do `const uniqueData2 = _.uniqBy(duplicateEmails)` I have an array of 797 unique data

Comment: If the duplicateEmails is an Array with email addresses like ["test@gmail.com", "test1@gmail.com"] You can use _.uniq(duplicateEmails);

Comment: Yes I delete the "Email of user"

Comment: So, now You have 883 unique emails from the CSV, and  797 emails in duplicateEmails. Right?

Comment: And how many items you got from the testDeleteEmails function?

Comment: from testDeleteEmails I have 869 items

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. So You got the same result for the 960 emails and 883 emails?

Comment: I have 797 now by using uniqueData wich is the number of duplicateEmails so the problem was indeed all duplicate email in my CSV